# How to get the attributes from a cookbook added to the runlist of a node?

Tags: shell, chef-infra, knife, chef-attributes

I have a cookbook `mycookbook` which is added to the runlist of a node `node_address`. Now I want to retrieve the attributes of `mycookbook` in JSON format  from the node.

In this case, I have access to the node so I can ssh in that node and run commands.

I would also like to learn what knife commands to use to get the attributes in JSON format from the cookbook which is added to the runlist of a node.

Answer (score 0):

if you added a cookbook to a node run-list and converged the node  (by executing `chef-client` on the node), you can use [`knife node  show`](https://docs.chef.io/workstation/knife_node/)

```sh
knife node show node.example.com --format json --long
```